# variadic template, Range, C++

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, stdarray, non-type-template-parameter

Consider I have a struct.

```
template<typename T>
struct Range{
    T min, max;
    
    Range() = default;
    Range(T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(),T max = std::numeric_limits::max()) :
                                   min(min), max(max){
    } 
};
```

So this struct holds a range for any type T, and if not given it the range becomes the numeric limits of that type.
**Note: Of course I check for `T` to be `fundamental` type but this question is not about that.**

Now in my use case I want to have a struct like this

```
template<typename T,Range<T>...ranges>
struct Something{
    static std::array<Range<T>,sizeof...(ranges)> RANGES = {ranges...};
};
```

But when I want to "define" that something with this
 `using Defined = Something<int,Range<int>(100,200),Range<int>(200,300)>`
I get compile-time error, because `Range<T>` is non-type template parameter and I am not using `C++ 20`. So I went further and updated my range struct like this.

```
template<typename T, T MIN = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), T MAX = std::numeric_limits<T>::max()>
struct Range {
    T min = MIN, max = MAX;

    Range(T min, T max) : min(min), max(max) {}

    Range() = default;
};
```

And my `Something` struct's template becomes this `typename<T,typename... Args>` so now `using Defined = Something<int,Range<int,100,200>,Range<int,200,300>>` works. So at this point I've got 2 questions, *how can I statically assert for each of args to be a `Range<T,T min, T max>`* . The second questions is about storing that. Look, I know that I have to store `...Args` in a tuple, but if you look at my implementation of Range, *can I somehow wrap them in an `std::array<Range<T>,sizeof(args)>`?*

Comment: I've got a feeling that "_not using C++20_" is insufficient. What version are you using? In C++17 you could probably fold `std::is_same_v` or similar.

Comment: I am using C++17, the reason I don't use C++ 20 is that **clang compilers on the phones still does partial support for C++ 20**

Comment: Great, then Jarod42's answer will fit like a glove.

Comment: There is no `Range<T>` anymore. It's a `Range<T, t1, t2>`. So the type is now different depending on the min and max. Meaning you can't store different ranges in one array.

Comment: Notice that in your first version, constructor with all default value **is** a default constructor. (so you have twice).

Comment: @super I can, assume I have `Range<int,100,200> aRange` and now I create another range from this like this `Range<int> anotherRange = {arange.min,arange.max}` So I can create `Range<int>`s from any `Range<int,min,max>`;

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah thanks, kinda not noticed that)

Comment: @HrantNurijanyan: you have a problem, it should be `Range<int, ???, ???> anotherRange`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah you are right, compiler implicitly does that, thanks

Comment: Does anyone know is It O(1) time complexity for getting an element at index in a tuple?

Comment: You can still have `template <typename T, T...> struct Range;` with specializations (0, 2 arguments) and conversion from 2 to 0.

Comment: std::tuple access is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create trait `is_range`:

```
template <typename> struct is_range : std::false_type{};

template<typename T, T MIN, T MAX>
struct is_range<Range<T, MIN, MAX> : std::true_type{};
```

and then fold expression (C++17)

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct Something{
    static_assert((is_range<Ts>::value && ...));
    static std::tuple<Ts...> RANGES;
};
```

Comment: I like this idea, could you please also advice on my second question, or shall I create a new question for that?

Comment: As types differ, you cannot store them in array.

Comment: I wrote a comment about that in the question part, please read that)